# bat file: parse from multiple files and write to csv

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have been researching how to write this bat file I need - and I have come to a dead end. Not sure what is going wrong.

The problem/goal: I have huge txt files I must parse 5 key values from. The first 195 lines of each text file is essentially garbage I am not interested in.

There are 5 text files, 1 each resides in 5 sub-directories. 
The goal is to write those 5 key values (tokens 7, 11, 19, 21 and 25) into a csv file. (there are 1800 of each of the 5 key values, per text file - making a total of 9000 lines for the csv file I create)

The code I've written fails when entering the first for loop, stating "do( was unexpected at this time"

This is my first time writing functions into a bat file, or requiring more than 1 for loop. I have tweaked my syntax in multiple places, but still get the same error. Obviously I am missing something, but I am not sure what. There may also be additional errors I am not yet aware of, since I can't even get into my first loop.

Code:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set fileout="C:\ffmpeg\fit.csv"

for /R %%f in (*.txt) do (
set THEFILE=%%f
call :setTokens
goto TheEnd
)

:setTokens
for /F "skip=195 tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('%THEFILE%') do(
    set the_line=%%A
    call :process_line
)

:process_line
for /F "tokens=7,11,19,21,25 delims= =:" %%a in ('%the_line%') do (
    set qp=%%a
    set slice=%%b
    set skip=%%c
    set size=%%d
    set y=%%e
    set OUTLINE=%qp%,",",%slice%,",",%skip%,",",%size%,",",%y%  
    echo %OUTLINE%>>%fileout%
)

:TheEnd
```

Comment: Since you are *changing* the value of `qp` etc *within* the loop, you need to extract the value using `!qp!` (as you have invoked *delayedexpansion*) - `%qp%` will give you the variable's value *at parse time*. This is assuming you've invoked aschipfl's change, and note JosefZ's advice that since you are not manipulating the values that you assign to `qp`, then you can use the raw `metavariable`s `%%a`..`%%e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next code snippet should do the job for you:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set fileout="C:\ffmpeg\fit.csv"

>>"%fileout%" (
  for /R %%F in (*.txt) do (
    for /F "usebackq skip=195 delims=" %%A in ("%%~F") do (
      for /F "tokens=7,11,19,21,25 delims==: " %%a in ("%%~A") do (
        echo %%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e
      )
    )
  )
)
:TheEnd
```

For the sake of completeness, next code snippet shows and repairs (most of) flagrant mistakes in the script (see all `rem` comments below):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set fileout="C:\ffmpeg\fit.csv"

for /R %%f in (*.txt) do (
      rem  strip ↓ incidental surroundig doble quotes (be on the safe side)
  set "THEFILE=%%~f"
  call :setTokens
      rem `goto TheEnd` here would end the %%f loop just after the 1st iteration 
)
    rem next goto moved from inside `for /R` body
goto TheEnd


:setTokens
    rem ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓           ↓            quotes ↓         ↓    ↓ space
for /F "usebackq skip=195     delims=" %%A in ("%THEFILE%") do (
    rem removed `tokens=*` ↑  as `delims=` suffices
    set "the_line=%%~A"
    call :process_line
)
    rem return from subroutine
goto :eof

:process_line
    rem         order of delimiters ↓↓↓          ↓          ↓ quotes
for /F "tokens=7,11,19,21,25 delims==: " %%a in ("%the_line%") do (
    set qp=%%a
    set slice=%%b
    set skip=%%c
    set size=%%d
    set y=%%e
        rem note that all `,",",` denoted below are taken literally
        rem         ↓↓↓↓↓       ↓↓↓↓↓      ↓↓↓↓↓      ↓↓↓↓↓
    set OUTLINE=%qp%,",",%slice%,",",%skip%,",",%size%,",",%y%
    rem echo %OUTLINE%>>%fileout%
    rem you need to apply delayed expansion as follows: 
    set OUTLINE=!qp!,!slice!,!skip!,!size!,!y!
    echo !OUTLINE!>>%fileout%
        rem       ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ redirection could be moved
        rem                ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ and lopp variables used directly 
    rem >>"%fileout%" echo %%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e
)
    rem return from subroutine
goto :eof

:TheEnd
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`>>`, `2>&1` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: Thank you - this worked!
Even better - thank you for the resources. I have been working from the first reference you posted - the others are much appreciated.